# AppleScript & Notes App

Tags: applescript, macos, notes.app

Is it possible to use AppleScript to change the font in the Notes App?

I am not very familiar with AppleScript, so I may have missed something, but my attempts to change the font have failed. The Dictionary makes no mention of anything useful, but then it also omits the `body` property of `note`, so I I’m not sure.

This is on 10.11.1 El Capitan and I don’t like the default font that Notes currently uses.

Thanks

Comment: The dictionary does NOT omit the body property of a note class. It's there, and you can see that the body of a note is stored as HTML. El Capitan 10.11 added increased individualized styling including fonts. If you bold a word it is saves as a <b> tag, however, if you highlight and change font on a specific word, that is saved elsewhere, so it is not accessible via applescript.  More info on scripting notes here: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/notes/

Comment: @jweaks I see it now, but the dictionary is a bit confusing on this: it doesn’t appear as one of the note properties in the top part, but does in the body. I have checked that link before, and I found it useful, but obviously it doesn’t specifically mention fonts. Bummer about the font itself not being scriptable. Thanks